# Google chart point color

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to change point color in Google chart api, something like this:

From this:
[image: Default]

To this:       [image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try taking a look at this [**jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/jdkKm/) created by asgallant [**here**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-visualization-api/Nz0aN6mucOQ)

*"There is **no support in the API for making lines and data points have different colors in the same series**.  You can **fake what you want**, though, by using a DataView with your data repeated in two columns.  Make the first series colored 'black' and the second colored 'red' with lineWidth = 0 and pointSize > 0."*

From the Example:

```
var options = {
        title: 'Load vs Length',
        titlePosition: 'out',
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Length (inch)',
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0
            },
            format: '#.000'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Load (pound)',
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0
            }
        },
        series: { //Create 2 separate series to fake what you want. One for the line             and one for the points
            0: {
                color: 'black',
                lineWidth: 2
            },
            1: {
                color: 'red',
                lineWidth: 0,
                pointSize: 5
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, a simple pointColor would be nice from Google, but anyway... cheers, works for me!

Comment: Yeah, there should be a simpler way, but I suppose they didn't want to introduce any confusion for intersecting lines. Glad it helped! =)

Comment: Can we do the same for charts which have multiple lines ?

Answer (score 6):

Thank you for your suggestion. However, series 1 doesn't work for me:
Following code, prints the line blue but doesn't show the points. If I switch 1 and 0. Then it does show the points in red, but there's no line. Before instead of series I just had pointSize: 4, right after the hAxis. That worked, except the points and the line where the same color.

```
{title: 'progress',

  vAxis: {
          title: 'Grade',  
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, 
          gridlines: {count: 7}, 
          viewWindow: { min: 0, 
                        max: 100, 
                        valueLabelsInterval: 20}
        },

  hAxis: {
          title: 'Q date',  
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}, 
          slantedText: true
        },

  series: {
          0: {lineWidth: 2},
          1: {
             color: 'red',
             lineWidth: 0,
             pointSize: 4
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same for charts which have multiple lines ?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by adding an individual style column to each point, like this:

[image]

```
  var data_timeline = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data_timeline.addColumn('string', 'Year'); // Implicit domain label col.
  data_timeline.addColumn('number', 'Students'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
  data_timeline.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); // annotation role col.
  data_timeline.addColumn({type:'string', role:'style'}); // style col.      
  data_timeline.addRows([
    ['2010-2011', 85, '85', 'point { size: 7; shape-type: diamond; fill-color: #005b82; }'],
    ['2011-2012', 67, '67', 'point { size: 7; shape-type: diamond; fill-color: #005b82; }'],
    ['2012-2013', 34, '34', 'point { size: 7; shape-type: diamond; fill-color: #005b82; }'],
  ]);      

  var options_timeline = {
    hAxis: { textStyle: { color: '#444444'} },
    vAxis: { baselineColor: '#cccccc', textPosition: 'none', minValue: 0 },
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    lineWidth: 3,
    pointsVisible: true,
    colors: ['#b7c72a'],
  };

  var chart_timeline = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_timeline'));
  chart_timeline.draw(data_timeline, options_timeline);
```